# Trigger Angular Material toast on state change

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, angular-material, angular-services

I'm currently developing an [AngularJS](https://angularjs.org/) web application, which is setup and using [Angular Material](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/toast).

I have implemented the [Angular Material Toast](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/toast) feature, without any problems.

Also, I have setup several views using [ui-router](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router) - 1. Index, 2. Parent & 3. Child (See attached).

I'm able to view and click through Prev/Next states:

```
#/dashboard/raiding-the-rails/1
```

So what is the problem? Well I want to be able to trigger specific toast messages depending and relevant to the current state ID.

e.g `#/dashboard/raiding-the-rails/5` will display toast message 5.

I tried setting up a service/factory and couldn't figure out how todo this!

I even subscribed to [egghead.io](http://egghead.io) just to try and find a pro solution!

Any help and advice would really help!
Thank you!!!

**Diagram:** 
[image: Screenshot]

**App:**

```
(function(angular, undefined){
  "use strict";
  var am = angular.module('virtual-fitting', ['ngAnimate', 'ngAria', 'ngMaterial', 'ui.router', 'firebase']);
  // Beginning
  am.config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
    $stateProvider
      .state('authentication', {
        url: '/authentication',
        templateUrl: '../views/authentication.html'
      })
      .state('dashboard', {
        url: '/dashboard',
        controller: 'dashboardCtrl as dashboard',
        templateUrl: '../views/dashboard.html'
      })
      .state('dashboard.bodytype', {
        url: '/body-type',
        templateUrl: '../views/dashboard.body-type.html'
      })
      .state('dashboard.raidingtherails', {
        abstract: true,
        url: '/raiding-the-rails',
        templateUrl: '../views/dashboard.raiding-the-rails.html'
      })
      .state('dashboard.raidingtherails.dress', {
        url: '/:id',
        controller: 'raidingtherailsCtrl as raiding',
        templateUrl: '../views/dashboard.raiding-the-rails.dress.html'
      })
      .state('dashboard.collection', {
        url: '/collection',
        templateUrl: '../views/dashboard.collection.html'
      })
      .state('dashboard.lovelist', {
        url: '/love-list',
        templateUrl: '../views/dashboard.love-list.html'
      })
      .state('dashboard.secondopinion', {
        url: '/second-opinion',
        templateUrl: '../views/dashboard.second-opinion.html'
      });
      $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/dashboard/raiding-the-rails/1');
  });
  // End
})(angular);
```

**Primary Controller:**

```
(function(angular, undefined) {
  "use strict";
  var am = angular.module('virtual-fitting');
  // Beginning
  am.controller('dashboardCtrl', function($scope, $state, $mdDialog, $mdToast) {
    var self = this;
    // FAB Speed Dial
    self.isOpen = false;
    self.selectedMode = 'md-scale';
    self.selectedDirection = 'down';
    // onClick State
    self.pageUrl = function(state) {
      $state.go(state);
    };
    // Dialog Show
    self.dialog = function($event, id) {
      $mdDialog.show({
        clickOutsideToClose: true,
        controller: function($mdDialog) {
          this.item = id;
          // Dialog Hide
          this.close = function() {
            $mdDialog.cancel();
          };
          this.submit = function() {
            $mdDialog.hide();
          };
        },
        controllerAs: 'dialog',
        templateUrl: '../views/dashboard.dialog.html',
        targetEvent: $event
      });
    };
    // Toast Setup
    self.toastPosition = angular.extend({}, {
      bottom: true,
      left: true
    });
    self.getToastPosition = function() {
      return Object.keys(self.toastPosition)
        .filter(function(pos) {
          return self.toastPosition[pos];
        })
        .join(' ');
    };
    // Toast Show
    self.showToast = function() {
      $mdToast.show({
        controller: function() {
          this.item = 'Hello';
          // Toast Hide
          this.hideToast = function() {
            $mdToast.hide();
          };
        },
        controllerAs: 'toast',
        templateUrl: '../views/dashboard.toast.html',
        hideDelay: 10000,
        position: self.getToastPosition()
      });
    };
  });
  // End
})(angular);
```

**Child Controller:**

```
(function(angular, undefined) {
  "use strict";
  var am = angular.module('virtual-fitting');
  // Beginning
  am.controller('raidingtherailsCtrl', function($scope, $state, $stateParams) {
    var self = this;
    self.id = $stateParams.id;
    self.prev = function() {
      self.minus = parseFloat(self.id) - parseFloat(1);
      $state.go('dashboard.raidingtherails.dress', {'id': self.minus});
    };
    self.next = function() {
      self.plus = parseFloat(self.id) + parseFloat(1);
      $state.go('dashboard.raidingtherails.dress', {'id': self.plus});
    };
  });
  // End
})(angular);
```

**Service (Deleted):**

```
(function(angular, undefined) {
  "use strict";
  var am = angular.module('virtual-fitting');
  // Beginning
  am.service('', function() {});
  // End
})(angular);
```

**Update:**
I tried using the following but as you can see the console.log is out putting the previous id instead of the correct & current id. Now I just need to trigger the message allocated to the state id! Any Ideas?

```
$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart',
  function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams){
    var test = $state.params.id;
    console.log(test);
  });
```

[image]

**Update**
After further Googling around and rewriting the above I finally managed to get the current state ID.

```
$rootScope.$watchCollection(function(){
  return $state.params;
}, function(){
    console.log($state.params.id);
});
```

[image]
**Answer**

```
// Toast Setup
    self.toastPosition = angular.extend({}, {
      bottom: true,
      left: true
    });
    self.getToastPosition = function() {
      return Object.keys(self.toastPosition)
      .filter(function(pos) {
        return self.toastPosition[pos];
      }).join(' ');
    };
    $rootScope.$watchCollection(function(){
      return $state.params;
    }, function(){
      // State ID (State Params)
      var stateID = $state.params.id;
      // Toast Messages
      var toastMessages = {
        "results": [
          {'id': '1', 'message':'Textured fabrics are what you want to look for, this will help.'},
          {'id': '2', 'message':'This dress is perfect for a Triangle body shape like yours, Kerry! Its a beautiful style too!'},
          {'id': '3', 'message':'Just click on a designers name to view their collection - We have some amazing dresses!'}
        ]
      };
      // Filter against State ID
      var toastMessage = $filter('filter')(toastMessages.results, {id: stateID})[0];
      // Prevent Undefined ID
      if(toastMessage){
        self.messageID = toastMessage.id;
      }
      // Check State ID against Message ID
      if(stateID === self.messageID) {
        // Show Toast
        $mdToast.show({
          controller: function() {
            this.item = toastMessage.message;
            // Hide Toast
            this.hideToast = function() {
              $mdToast.hide();
            };
          },
          controllerAs: 'toast',
          templateUrl: '../views/dashboard.toast.html',
          hideDelay: 10000,
          position: self.getToastPosition()
        });
      } else {
        // Hide Toast on 'IF' Fail
        $mdToast.hide();
      }
    });
```

Comment: Can you post a codepen? I'd be glad to take a look, but this is a bit too much to set up first.

Comment: Also, what exactly is the problem? Can you not figure out how to get the service up and running or are you having trouble figuring out how to detect when the state changes?

Comment: Both, I guess! I've spent all day trying to figure this out!!!

Comment: There is literally no relevant documentation online to help!

Comment: @MikeFeltman was the Github URL ok ?

Comment: I'm looking at it now.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/94353/discussion-between-adam-w-and-mike-feltman).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
// Toast Setup
    self.toastPosition = angular.extend({}, {
      bottom: true,
      left: true
    });
    self.getToastPosition = function() {
      return Object.keys(self.toastPosition)
      .filter(function(pos) {
        return self.toastPosition[pos];
      }).join(' ');
    };
    $rootScope.$watchCollection(function(){
      return $state.params;
    }, function(){
      // State ID (State Params)
      var stateID = $state.params.id;
      // Toast Messages
      var toastMessages = {
        "results": [
          {'id': '1', 'message':'Textured fabrics are what you want to look for, this will help.'},
          {'id': '2', 'message':'This dress is perfect for a Triangle body shape like yours, Kerry! Its a beautiful style too!'},
          {'id': '3', 'message':'Just click on a designers name to view their collection - We have some amazing dresses!'}
        ]
      };
      // Filter against State ID
      var toastMessage = $filter('filter')(toastMessages.results, {id: stateID})[0];
      // Prevent Undefined ID
      if(toastMessage){
        self.messageID = toastMessage.id;
      }
      // Check State ID against Message ID
      if(stateID === self.messageID) {
        // Show Toast
        $mdToast.show({
          controller: function() {
            this.item = toastMessage.message;
            // Hide Toast
            this.hideToast = function() {
              $mdToast.hide();
            };
          },
          controllerAs: 'toast',
          templateUrl: '../views/dashboard.toast.html',
          hideDelay: 10000,
          position: self.getToastPosition()
        });
      } else {
        // Hide Toast on 'IF' Fail
        $mdToast.hide();
      }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

From https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki#state-change-events

```
$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', 
function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams){ ... })
```

Will let you track when you change states. You would probably want to put this in in your main controller or on a [.run()](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/angular.Module#run) from right after you make/configure your module.

While you're setting up states, you can add the data property which holds an object where you can put arbitrary data. I'd recommend this for holding your strings that you want to display in the toasts, as an example:

```
.state('dashboard.raidingtherails', {
    abstract: true,
    url: '/raiding-the-rails',
    templateUrl: '../views/dashboard.raiding-the-rails.html',
    data: {
        toast: "Raiding the rails toast"
    }
})
```

Then in your onStateChangeStart you can reference `toState.data.toast`. If you do it like this you won't need a service/provider, though if you want more advanced functionality you may decide to make one anyway.

In addition, you can get URL parameters (the `/5` and the end of the url) using [ui-router](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/URL-Routing#url-parameters)'s URL parameters.

Comment: I tried using the below but the console.log was displaying the last state ID when clicking Next or Previous. So when I was on /5 it displayed 4 within the console...

    $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart',
      function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams){
        var test = $state.params.id;
        console.log(test);
      });

Comment: I've attached a screenshot above!

Comment: @AdamW. What's your problem now? you already get the current state, stateOnchange to trigger `toast`.

Comment: @ShaohaoLin I need to assign a toast message to specific state id's, e.g if I'm on state 5 then state 5 message will display!

Comment: In your update where you have `var test = $state.params.id;`, have you tried `toState.params.id`?